# Windows 7 prevent shutdown

Tags: windows, administration, shutdown, autoit, system-administration

I want to be able to prevent regular shutdown on windows 7. I found this AutoIt script but its not clicking the CANCEL button on force shutdown dialog really.

Someone can test it and tell me whats wrong exactly?

```
$WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11
GUIRegisterMsg($WM_QUERYENDSESSION, "Cancel_Shutdown")
$Hwnd = GUICreate("PreventShutdownGUI")
;~ GUISetSTate(@SW_SHOW)


_ShutdownBlockReasonCreate($hwnd, "Sorry, AutoIt > Windows")
TrayTip("Shutdown Blocker - Started", "Denies shutdowns from now on.", 20)
While Sleep(100)
WEnd
_ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy($hwnd)

Func _ShutdownBlockReasonCreate($Hwnd, $wStr)
    ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms...28VS.85%29.aspx
    ; Prog@ndy
    Local $aResult = DllCall("User32.dll", "int", "ShutdownBlockReasonCreate", "hwnd", $Hwnd, "wstr", $wStr)
    If @error Then Return SetError(1,0,0)
    Return $aResult[0]
EndFunc

Func _ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy($Hwnd)
    Local $aResult = DllCall("User32.dll", "int", "ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy", "hwnd", $Hwnd)
    If @error Then Return SetError(1,0,0)
    Return $aResult[0]
EndFunc

Func Cancel_Shutdown($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $WParam, $LParam)
    ; This HAS to be here to capture the endsession...
    AdlibRegister("Cancel_ShutdownResolver",50)
    Return False
EndFunc

Func Cancel_ShutdownResolver()
    Local $iOpt = Opt("WinTitleMatchMode",4),$hwnd = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:BlockedShutdownResolver]")
    Opt("WinTitleMatchMode",$iOpt)
    If $hwnd Then
        If @OSVersion = "WIN_7" Then ControlClick($hwnd,"","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
        If @OSVersion <> "WIN_7" Then ControlClick($hwnd,"","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]")
        AdlibUnRegister("Cancel_ShutdownResolver")
        TrayTip("Shutdown Blocker - Shutdown denied", "Denied shutdown successfull!", 5)
        _DeineFunktion()  ; <================ Hier musst du deine Funktion einfügen
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _DeineFunktion()
    MsgBox(0,"","Das hier ist deine Funktion ;) - Danach musst du erneut _ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy($hwnd) aufrufen, und einen neuen Shutdown machen.")
EndFunc
```

Comment: The code *just works* for me. Windows 7 English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like this is a way of preventing an `autoit` function getting killed..

`_deineFunction()` (German for your function) is the function you don't want killed.